# Ubuntu 10.04 notebook edition running slow

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, wubi

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 notebook edition inside Windows 7 through wubi installation on a Compaq Presario b1200 laptop.

But the graphics is very slow. When I choose the items in the left hand pane. It takes up to 15 seconds for the screen to react. What am I supposed to do? I tried to go to the device manager and see if there is a graphic driver that isn't installed but it said that there are no proprietary drivers available. What might be the cause of this problem, how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay looked up your VGA. Intel comes with total open source driver on Linux. That means, one have a full 3d acceleration and there is no need to install any driver by hand. (And there is no other driver). But. On Linux, Intel is got some quirks. It works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. Intel releases its driver frequent. Whether they ruined almost everything (due to moving some new stuff) or just fixed some stuff, they released it. Xorg (the graphical environment/GUI on Linux) merges it, uhm... implements it so to say, and the end user (you) will get it. And.. it looks like its based purely on luck whether you will get a smooth experience on a distro or not.

Okay okay but what can you do? Well, try other distros. I would go with openSUSE. I'm not a lizard, but I do like Yast, the package management, and its rock solid. If you prefer cutting edge, try Fedora, it comes with even newer drivers than Ubuntu and they update them whenever its needed. (Fedora and Ubuntu got different "policy". Like in 8.04 Ubuntu the TV out is crappy with Intel. Fedora just fixed it, done. Ubuntu? No way, its our policy not to fix it, so they wont include a small patch, they wont fix it. Ever. Period. So yeah. Some people prefer this, some prefer the other method.)

So just grab the openSUSE dvd and there you go.

---

**NOTE**: You should resize your partition and install Linux to a native free space. Open Start -> Right-click on Computer -> click on Manage. Double click Storage, Disk management. Here, you can do anything.

(If this feature-set is not enough for you, go with Acronis Disk Director suite. Grab an older copy from somewhere (doesnt matter if its torrent, just use a trial way, dont crack/key it). And thar u go.)

---

Oh and there is a page about this Intel issue: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/IntelPerformance Try these workarounds.

Comment: I'm afraid I might ruin the windows installation. That's why I'm just using wubi for ubuntu.

Comment: Hmm with Acronis Disk Director Suite you 're totally safe. I used it to play around my PC soo many times. If you manage to screw up your boot, just use your Windows DVD (so burn one out), and go to Recovery console. Type this: `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` and `bootrec.exe /fixboot` . That's it. You're done.